# Land a date to the dance.(meaning)

Tags: word-usage

https://youtu.be/ixWnosDTAls

What does "land a date to the dance" mean here? (Liv says this.)

And later on Joey was:

> I wish I had a twin who could help me **land** a date to the dance. I'd call him Michael.

Answer (score 3):

This usage of the word "land" comes from fishing terminology. To "land" something means to bring it to land from a boat, so in a literal sense the word is sometimes used in place of "caught" when talking about catching a fish and bring it back to land:

> I caught a fish.
>   I landed a fish.

In a figurative sense then, the word "land" or "landed" is used to mean that you *got* something, or *achieved* something, for example:

> I landed a job.
>   I landed a date.

In your sentence, the first person is trying to *get* a date for a dance, and he is wishing that he had some help in doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/land) provides this definition (among others):

> **land** (verb) = to get or achieve something good, especially in a way that seems easy or unexpected:
>
> - *He landed a senior editorial job.*

Therefore, your example can be rewritten as:

> I wish I had a twin who could help me **get** a date to the dance. I'd call him Michael.